# Set operations for filter values

Tags: python, set

Let's say I have a list column and I want to apply a filter to it. Here are the values in the column:

```
row  People
--------------------
1   ['Veli']
2   ['David']
3   ['David', 'Veli']
4   ['George']
5   ['David', 'George']
```

The user selects the values `Veli` and `David` in the options list of what they want to check for. Then, here are the various filter operations they can do with the corresponding rows that should be returned:

1. People contains any value from list --> 1, 2, 3, 5
2. People contains no value from list --> 4
3. People contains all values from list --> 3
4. People contains only values from list --> 1, 2, 3

How would these four operations be expressed with sets? For example, the first one might be:

```
rows = (set(['Veli']), set(['David']), set(['Veli', 'David']), set(['George']), set(['George', 'David']))
criteria = {'David', 'Veli'}
filter(lambda row: row&criteria, rows)
# (set(['Veli']), set(['David']), set(['Veli', 'David']), set(['George', 'David']))
```

How would I express the other three operations?

Comment: What are you using for the rows and columns?

Comment: @Barmar it's just hardcoded in python. The part that says `rows = ...` is all I'm using.

Comment: Where do the row numbers come from? That's why I thought it was a Pandas dataframe.

Comment: Oh I just added those in the question so easier to refer to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. People contains any value from list --> 1, 2, 3, 5
> 2. People contains no value from list --> 4
> 3. People contains all values from list --> 3
> 4. People contains only values from list --> 1, 2, 3

Using [set methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```py
rows = (set(['Veli']), set(['David']), set(['Veli', 'David']), set(['George']), set(['George', 'David']))
criteria = {'David', 'Veli'}
def show(sets):
    print(*(rows.index(s) + 1 for s in sets))

show(filter(criteria.intersection, rows))
show(filter(criteria.isdisjoint, rows))
show(filter(criteria.issubset, rows))
show(filter(criteria.issuperset, rows))
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZBNCsJADIVxO6fIzhmtgjsR3AnewI240Da1EZkpk6k_iCdx40YP5WlMW5WCgrMZ8vIlL7zLPT-GzNnr9VaEtDd8tNC7PcMYNGPQ8_YMt9RemAjqcrLcUdKoq3YEX_oUnV_jt9BAjYo9BfS0FLfTS5Z-tfKsEkyBM7cv72AzUiAv92SD7ujyxD7ZBA-aDXRhAKnzwEAWKtooVY2mtBUD_faREfkZ40DORlBuEfQ3yQnxxsnAP46LlXj-p_LS-cPVab9Cf4f_BA)):

```
1 2 3 5
4
3
1 2 3
```

Or if you insist on using lambdas instead of the already existing methods ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuha3GNuL8suLFWwVNIpTSzSi1cNSczLVYzV1FCBcl8SyzBQkPlhaRwFD3D01vyg9FVMASakmV3JRZklqUWYi0LZqqDBQHmxkLVdKappCcUZ-OcgdxZpWXApAUFCUmVeioaUBcqJeZl5KaoVGsaaCtoKhQlp-kUKxQmaeAli1JhcXWGtaZg7QAo2cxNyklEQFoC4rEKGgpgCzWQfEB6nHpTwvv4RULSDldrakqbfBVA-JD2i0wKIHAA)):

```py
show(filter(lambda row: row & criteria, rows))
show(filter(lambda row: not row & criteria, rows))
show(filter(lambda row: row >= criteria, rows))
show(filter(lambda row: row <= criteria, rows))
```

Note that `isdisjoint` is more efficient than `not row & criteria`, as it doesn't build a set and stops as soon as it finds any shared element. Sadly there's no similarly efficient `intersects` method, that was [suggested but met resistance](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-ideas@python.org/thread/AVRZEYTDQS7EWBR22TV673NIRKODGOTW/). So similarly efficient ways are:

```
show(filter(lambda row: not criteria.isdisjoint(row), rows))
show(filterfalse(criteria.isdisjoint, rows))
```

(With `filterfalse` from `itertools`)

Comment: thanks. Are there any other "practical filters" that can be applied to a set? Or are the above 4 the main ones?

Comment: @David542 You could also use at least proper subset, proper superset, equality, inequality, difference (both directions) or union. Whether they're "practical" depends on what you mean with that and on your needs, I guess. I added a link to the set  documentation which shows methods and operators.

Answer (score 1):

These are all basic set operations

1. `row & criteria`
2. `not (row & criteria)`
3. `row & criteria == criteria`
4. `row & criteria == row`